# Stuck in Tenpenny's Tower

Tags: fallout-3

I went to Tenpenny's Tower and tried to use diplomacy to let the ghouls in. After several attempts I was stuck, so I decided to let them in the rough way.

I opened the basement passage and went to take a look at the carnage.

Before the ghouls slayed everyone, I was trying to enter my room but I was told that it wasn't safe to enter at that moment. After the ghouls slayed everyone, I was trying to enter my room (I have found one or two keys for it) but I was told that I needed a key.

I gave up on that, but I wanted at least *some* reward from Roy, and I discovered him laying dead on the floor of the main hall. Can I still get a reward for the mission?

Comment: Roy isn't killed as part of the natural progression of the questline. As he's a non-essential NPC, he probably died in the fighting, somehow, which means you no longer have anyone to give you your reward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot get a reward for the mission anymore.

> Roy isn't killed as part of the natural progression of the questline. As he's a non-essential NPC, he probably died in the fighting, somehow, which means you no longer have anyone to give you your reward.
>
> *This was originally posted as a comment by Raven Dreamer, but it is the correct answer, so I'm posting it as an answer.*